# Make all the items in folder inherit folder permissions( sharePoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, permissions, library

We have multiple folders in each library and each folder contains huge no of docs.
All the docs inside folder used to have inheritance from parent folder.

Some have all the items inside folder lost inheritance.Is there a way to find the reason behind the broken permission, and revoke that.

We have thousand's of docs so there is no way that some one manually broke inheritance

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell to reset inheritance

```
$webUrl = "http://mycoolsite"
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $list = $web.Lists["mycoollib"]


    foreach ($item in $list.items) {
        $item.ResetRoleInheritance()
    }
```

Also to get items that do not inherit permission you can use following powershell script

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://mycoolsite"
$list = $web.Lists["mycoollib"]
$list.Folders | ft Name, HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```